# Scaling or, mapping each entry of numpy array to another range of values

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to map reinforcement learning continuous action values `range(-1.0,1.0)` to real output.

Suppose I have numpy action array `actions =  np.array([-1., 0.2, -0.3, 0.5])`. Values for the array may be `actions.min = -1.` and `actions.max = 1.`.

Now,I need to map each entry to separate range for example

- actions[0] mapped to range(-0.4 , 1.54)

  actions[1] mapped to range(1.4 , 1.54)

  actions[2] mapped to range(-2.4 , 2.0)

  actions[3] mapped to range(-1.54 , 0.4)

So, Mapped action `mapped_actions = np.array([-0.4, 1.484, -0.86, -0.085])`

My current solution is as followes:

```
import numpy as np

actions = np.array([-1., 0.2, -0.3, 0.5])
mapped_low_high = np.array([[-0.4, 1.54], [1.4, 1.54],[-2.4, 2.], [-1.54, 0.4]])

mapped_actions = np.zeros_like(actions)

for i in range(actions.shape[0]):
    mapped_actions[i] = np.interp(actions[i], (-1., 1.), mapped_low_high[i])
```

###### Is there are a better way to map  actions array to mapped_actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping with numpy arrays is slow. It is faster to write a vectorized function that can operate on the entire array at once. Since we know that the given array will always be between -1 and 1 and we have an array of the new range, the code is a simple function that maps from one range to the other. The general technique is to map the original data to `[0, 1]` and then map that to `[a, b]`.

```py
import numpy as np

actions = np.array([-1., 0.2, -0.3, 0.5])
mapped_low_high = np.array([[-0.4, 1.54],
                            [1.4, 1.54],
                            [-2.4, 2.],
                            [-1.54, 0.4]])


def remap(arr, mappings):
    out = arr.copy()
    a, b = mappings.T

    # remap out to [0,1]
    # assumes arr is [-1,1]
    out += 1.
    out /= 2.

    # remap out to [a,b]
    out *= b - a
    out += a
    return out


remapped = remap(actions, mapped_low_high)  # array([-0.4  ,  1.484, -0.86 , -0.085])
```

Comment: It's probably easier to put this in a single line, `return a + (b-a)*(arr + 1)/2`

Comment: Yes, but I opted to break it up into multiple lines so I could explain the process more clearly.

Comment: I was secretly hoping for some `numpy` magic function. But the Answer is efficient. I will wait 24hrs., and then accept this as the answer